# Difficulties copying files over NFS

Tags: java, nfs

I have a NFS mount which I am trying to copy a file to in my Java application.

Apache Commons `FileUtils.copy()` results in a "Failed to copy full contents..." message after comparing source and destination file lengths. However, when I browse the filesystem I can verify that the files are identical.

Java NIO's `Files.copy()` results in an `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`. An empty file with zero permissions is created.

For a sanity check, I ran the code against a non-NFS directory and all is well. I am guessing that there's some sort of asynchronous behaviour going on.

The export is declared as follows:

```
/mnt/gluster *(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

One thing to note is that this is a FUSE-mounted distributed filesystem using Gluster. I don't know if this is of any relevance. My NFS knowledge is a touch patchy so I'm hoping I've just forgotten to do something.

For completeness, the NFS server is a Ubuntu box and I'm mounting it on a Mac.

Comment: Can you make the copy with a plain `cp` command in the terminal? I am not sure your issue is related to NFS, which should give you a file system abstraction ...

Comment: I can, thanks. I've subsequently created a regular (non Gluster) export and my application works fine.

I suspect the issue is because I've naively exported the Gluster filesystem rather than using Gluster's dedicated NFS server. I'll add this as an answer once I'm successful.